# Grouping database results within while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, grouping

I am running a while loop to return all the results of a mysqli query but I want to use php to group the results.

My code is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['total'] >0)//row['total'] is found out within the query itself
{

  $recipeWords = str_word_count(preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $row['title']));
  if($countTerms == $recipeWords)
  {
      echo "<h2>Exact Match</h2>";?>
      <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
      <a href="recipe_details.php?id=<?php echo $row['recipeID']?>">
      <img src="images/recipes/<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']?>" />
      <h4><?php echo $row['title']?></h4></a> 
      </div><?php
  }
  elseif($countTerms == ($recipeWords-1))
  {
      echo "<h2>Closest Matches</h2>";?>
      <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
      <a href="recipe_details.php?id=<?php echo $row['recipeID']?>">
      <img src="images/recipes/<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']?>" />
      <h4><?php echo $row['title']?></h4></a> 
      </div><?php
   }
   else
   {
      echo "<h2>Other Suggestions</h2>";?>
      <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
      <a href="recipe_details.php?id=<?php echo $row['recipeID']?>">
      <img src="images/recipes/<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']?>" title="<?php echo $row['title']?>" />
      <h4><?php echo $row['title']?></h4></a> 
      </div><?php

   }
}
}?>
```

What I am trying to do is group the results so that:

- all the exact matches are displayed first
- then I want all the records where all but one of the keywords are found
- then the rest

at the moment they are being displayed on what seems a random order.

Comment: Store them in some variables instead of printing them, then print the variable. Example: declare: `$closestMatches = ""; $otherSuggestions = ""; $exactMatches = "";` Then, into each if, instead of echoing the content, just append it to the variable: example: `$exactMatches .= "content of exactMatches. Access rows in this way: {$row['YourRow']} <-- this will parse the result into the string";` Then echo them in the order you want. Example: `echo "{$exactMatches} <hr /> {$otherSuggestions} <hr /> {$closestMatches}";` If you're planning other categories, please use an associative array to store.

Comment: If you want to I can parse you the whole code you need to try down there. The logic is quite easy anyway :)

Comment: yeah if you would that would be great, im gonna have a shot at doing it too, see if i can get it working, will be good a good learning curb also :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['total'] >0)//row['total'] is found out within the query itself
{
  $recipeWords = str_word_count(preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $row['title']));

  $exactMatches = "";
  $closestMatches = "";
  $otherSuggestions = "";

  if($countTerms == $recipeWords)
  {
      $exactMatches .= <<<EXACT_MATCH
          <h2>Exact Match</h2>
          <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
          <a href="recipe_details.php?id={$row['recipeID']}">
          <img src="images/recipes/{$row['image']}" alt="{$row['title']}" title="{$row['title']}" />
          <h4>{$row['title']}</h4></a> 
          </div>
EXACT_MATCH;
  }
  elseif($countTerms == ($recipeWords-1))
  {
      $closestMatches .= <<<CLOSEST_MATCH
          <h2>Closest Match</h2>
          <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
          <a href="recipe_details.php?id={$row['recipeID']}">
          <img src="images/recipes/{$row['image']}" alt="{$row['title']}" title="{$row['title']}" />
          <h4>{$row['title']}</h4></a> 
          </div>
CLOSEST_MATCH;
   }
   else
   {

    $otherSuggestions .= <<<OTHER_SUGGESTIONS
      <h2>Other Suggestions</h2>
      <div class="fluid recipeContainerSmall">
      <a href="recipe_details.php?id={$row['recipeID']}">
      <img src="images/recipes/{$row['image']}" alt="{$row['title']}" title="{$row['title']}" />
      <h4>{$row['title']}</h4></a> 
      </div>
OTHER_SUGGESTIONS;
   }

   // ECHO in the order you want to...

   echo $exactMatches . $closestMatches . $otherSuggestions;
}
}?>
```

As asked by you above, please try this code.

Please note that I've used [HEREDOCS](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html) to simplify the parsing of the data.

Comment: thanks mate, that is basically what i came up with minus the usage of HEREDOCS :)

Comment: @user2886669: heredocs are not necessary and not used that much, but I'm pretty confident that in such cases they may be very useful, in order to don't have to change most of the code :P